# How can I remove the "Desktop" folder under Quick Access in the File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Hey I find the "Desktop" folder in Windows File Explorer very annoying with frequent accidental clicks. So I want to remove it but I had no luck so far.

I have successfully removed other entries like "Network" and "OneDrive" some time before but I can't seem to find any way of removing the "Desktop" entry.

I only need Quick Access there, nothing else.

[Example image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owO4U.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In Explorer, go to the VIEW tab and then click the NAVIGATION PANE button. Make sure the bottom 3 options are all unchecked.